# Why would the default allocationSize property for a @SequenceGenerator annotation in JPA be 50?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, sequence

I was looking through the hibernate source when I realized that the default value for thge allocationSize property of a @SequenceGenerator is 50.

As per the source...

```
/**
 * (Optional) The amount to increment by when allocating
 * sequence numbers from the sequence.
 */
int allocationSize() default 50;
```

Any idea why this would be 50 and not 1?  Wouldn't this mean your primary keys by default would go 1, 50, 100, 150, etc?  It seems to me that incrementing by 1 is a lot more common and makes more sense?

Answer (score 1):

I randomly found out this afternoon [this discussion](https://community.jboss.org/thread/107819?tstart=0&_sscc=t) where you can find a post from [Emmanuel Bernard](https://community.jboss.org/people/epbernard) stating it is a matter of efficiency though not the behaviour people expect.